# load the source code comment into a string object

Tags: c++

Is there in C++ (MS platform specific and VC compiler specific solutions are also ok) ability (probably some hack? something from metaprogramming? ) to load a content of the comment into class variable?

The reason why I'm asking : there is a set of headers (.h), each one of these contains detailed description of the class(es) logic at the beginning of the .h file in doxygen-formatted comment.

In other hand , there is a requirement to print the same description in command line (in case user specifies some option like my_program.exe --help module_name

Need to avoid the storing equal descriptions in two for each module (.h) places .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there should be no direct method as the comments are effectively removed before they reach the compiler.

Your best option is probably to use doxygen to extract the documentation and have it export the documentation in XML format. Then you it should be possible to parse the XML documentation.

You can either parse the documentation during build time and generate C++ code that contains the selected parts of the documentation or you can bundle the XML documentation with the program and then parse the documentation at runtime.